# I have Network Error on my react-native application requests when i'm using Psiphon on my android device

Tags: axios, react-native

I have a react-native project that when I'm using psiphon vpn, my post requests to API return NetworkError. I don't have any idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, using vpn like psiphon did not affect post requests. your problem may relate to your server policy (for example i know an sms panel that blocks requests from vpn in iran!). if its your own server, try changing your policies or call server support center.

Comment: i have changed the server , but its still the same way